# Rails whenever gem error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using whenever gem to create some cron job to fetch the data from a remote database. 
My question is , does whenever gem has any functionality to handle errors? suppose connection to db failed during retrieval. Or is there any otherway in rails to read the error from cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

whenere just generate the crontab. If you want some feature describe, you just need implement it in your task